# How to use Spark's API distinct()?

Tags: api, apache-spark

I checked the definition of the API `distinct()` in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html),
it says

> Return a new dataset that contains the distinct elements of the source dataset.

But what's the rule for splitting the source dataset?

Suppose my dataset contains 100 lines and my program would process it line by line, if I use distinct() to split my dataset, say 300 tasks, would the result be different from splitting 100 tasks?

Answer (score 1):

**Distinct()**

You cannot use `distinct()` to split your data set, it just removes duplicates, therefore you'll get the same amount or less elements as result. You can set `numTasks`to change the [level of parallelism](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#reducing-the-processing-time-of-each-batch).

> Cluster resources can be under-utilized if the number of parallel tasks used in any stage of the computation is not high enough.

*Example*

Data set ((1), (2), (2), (3)) becomes ((1), (2), (3)).

**Splitting elements**

To split an element, for example splitting a line in a text file into words, you could use `flatMap`.

> Similar to map, but each input item can be mapped to 0 or more output items (so func should return a Seq rather than a single item).

Have a look at the [word count example](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Then what should I do to split data set on Spark application and make sure my program could run concurrently?

Comment: By the way, what's the meaning of the parameter of distinct()? seems named "numPartition"

Comment: @fanhk: To use Spark, you'll need a [RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#resilient-distributed-datasets-rdds) and when using a RDD, you don't have to setup concurrency yourself, it's built-in. I added answers to your other questions in my post.